# Javascript case insensitive regex without flags

Tags: javascript, .net, regex, devexpress

Situation:

MVC+DevExpress .NET

Client-side validation based on server-side attributes (like **[RegularExpression("^con|prn|aux$")]**)

Is there a way to make validation case-insensitive?

I cannot add **i** flag, because RegExp object is created inside DevExpress client-side code by

**var regEx = new RegExp(this.pattern);**

.NET-style inline modifiers, like **(?i)** return "Unexpected quantifier" error.

Ugly alternative is writing something like **^[Cc][Oo][Nn]|[Pp][Rr][Nn]|[Aa][Uu][Xx]$**

Comment: I guess you know that flags can be passed as the second argument to `new RegExp`, like `new RegExp(pattern, "ig")`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Creating_a_Regular_Expression

Comment: I cannot modify RegExp creation code. It is hardcoded somewhere inside DevExpress resources.

Comment: Why not just lowercase the string you're trying to match?

Comment: Then you'll have to take the ugly alternative. Note that `|` takes even lower precedence than `^` and `$`, so you'll either need to use `^[Cc][Oo][Nn]$|^[Pp][Rr][Nn]$|^[Aa][Uu][Xx]$` or non-capturing parens `^(?:[Cc][Oo][Nn]|[Pp][Rr][Nn]|[Aa][Uu][Xx])$`

Comment: I can control only regular expression string. Other stages of validation are automated and cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Once the javascript RegExp object has been created, you can't change the regular expression or the flags.  But, you could get the original regex source using the `.source` property and then create a new RegExp object with the newly desired flags.